# Get the pixels which are colliding with the Surface

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, pygame-surface

Right now, I have a collision detection in pygame which checks if two rctangles overlap or not...what I am trying to do is check the transparency of a the surface and if the alpha value is less then 10, stop player from walking into it..

Currently, Im doing this:

```
for i in range(0,self.rect.w):
    for j  in range(0,self.rect.h):
        if player.rect.collidepoint((i,j)) and self.image.get_at((i,j))[3]<10:
            #STOP PLAYER
```

But it is a real pain on the Processor. Is there another way to get the collision pixel coordinates in pygame??

Comment: The most obvious thing would be to only check pixels within the intersection of the rectangles that bound both objects.  As an aside, I do a fair amount of image processing and am always suspect of functions like `get_pixel` being called in a tight loop.  I have no idea how python optimizes that though.  I would hope it gets inlined.

Comment: Also, flip your loop.  If the pixels are stored in a contiguous array (they should be) then it is almost certainly row order, so loop that way to avoid cache misses.  You want your `x` variable (`i`) to vary more rapidly than y.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pygame.mask.Mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.overlap) objects and [`overlap()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.overlap) or [`overlap_mask()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.overlap_mask).

[`overlap()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.overlap) :

> Returns the first point of intersection encountered between this *mask* and *othermask*.
> [...]
> Returns point of intersection or `None` if no intersection.

[`overlap_mask()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.overlap_mask):

> Returns a *Mask*, the same size as this *mask*, containing the overlapping set bits between this *mask* and *othermask*.

A mask can be created form a [`pyame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) with [`pygame.mask.from_surface()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.from_surface)-

e.g.:

```py
player_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(player.image)
self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
```

```py
offset = (player.rect.x - self.rect.x), (player.rect.y - self.rect.y)
first_intersection_point = self.mask.overlap(player_mask , offset)
if first_intersection_point:
    print("hit")
```